# Dropbox icon does not appear in sharing tray

Tags: java, android, android-intent, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a share button in my app that allows the sharing of the png/txt/pdf/etc.. files created in my app.

When I click on it, the sharing Android tray appears with all the apps that can be used for sharing. Many apps are displayed (Gmail, Drive, Whatsapp, Telegram, Skype, OneDrive, etc...) but not Dropbox (that is installed on my device).

Here is the code I use for sharing :

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");      
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailTitle);

    String text = "xxxxxx";

    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);

    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);   

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = getUris();

    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."), 12);
```

What could I do to have also Dropbox in the list of apps proposed by the system for sharing?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You have no control over what to show in Share tray. You can just specify what your intention is. I mean what your Intent will share if the type of the intent is supported by any application installed, it will automatically be populated by the System in the Share tray

Some sample code to send a file

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        intent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via"));
```